# OAuth2: Update refresh token along with the access token or not?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0

When it comes to update the access token of a client with OAuth2 the client might have a refresh token for that matter, here is where I see some **disagreement**:

Should you update the refresh token and invalidate the old one with every *access token update request* **or** should you keep sending the same refresh token and if so, when do we change it? do we change it at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will depends on the authorization server that you are using. From OAuth 2.0 specification point of view, sending a new refresh token in token refresh response is optional.

From [section 1.5 of OAuth 2.0 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.5)

> The authorization server authenticates the client and validates the
> refresh token, and if valid, issues a new access token (**and,
> optionally, a new refresh token**).

So it will depend on the exact implementation. Specific details should be included in your authorization server's documentation.

Also, one thing to note is that it is advisable to code in a way that even refresh token can expire after some time. Refer what [Google say about their token expiration](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2#expiration). Tokens can expire when they were not used for a long time or when a user revoke tokens issued on-behalf of him/her. This will be the case even when refresh tokens do not get updated in token refresh response.

Comment: I fully agree with this answer. In any case and if a new refresh token is in the response, you should discard the old one and save the latest.